# Is it possible to SSH to all network clients from a Bash exec?

Tags: bash, ssh, ip, arp

I'm writing a shell script that I want to be able to run some command, like `arp -a`, to get the IPs of everyone on the network and then try SSHing to each of them in turn. Problem is, I have no idea how to send the IPs from `arp -a` to the SSH command without typing the IP in manually (not going to work, as I'm writing an executable file.) Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: You can write a small script to extract the IP in from `arp` and process each one. You can use `bash` loop, or other tools (`xargs`) to process multiple IP.

Bash solution

```
#! /bin/bash
  # Read arp line like: '_gateway (192.168.215.3) at 00:52:58:e7:cf:5f [ether] on ens33`
while read tag ip x ; do
  # Strip leading and trailing characters from the IP
  ip=${ip:1:-1}
  # Execute ssh
  ssh ... "$ip"
done <<< "$(arp -a)"
```

Update bash version BEFORE 4.2:

Based on input in comment from @cyrus.

Using negative length on substring was added in bash 4.2. For older older versions, use the following instead of `ip=${ip:1:-1}` to remove leading '(' and trailing ')'

```
 ip=${ip#(} ; ip=${ip%)}
```

Comment: I think this would work, except bash throws an error when it gets to `ip=${ip:1:-1}`, specifically regarding `-1`. Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you post the error ? I'm using bash 4.0 with no issue. Can you post bash version you use (`bash --version`)

Comment: The version I'm using is 3.2.57 (MacOS)

Comment: `${var:start:-len}` was added with version 4.2.